# Draw repeating shapes with inset in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following shape drawn with some color & linewidth:

```
struct CustomShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: rect.height))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            CustomShape()
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 5)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

I'd like to draw 2 (possibly more) more rectangles inside the first one each with a different color & line width? Seems like I need the shape to conform to InsettableShape and I could then use stroke border but I'm not sure how.

Representative image:
[image]

Comment: Your shape looks like a triangle to me... What do you mean by "I'd like to draw 2 more rectangles inside the first one each with a different color & line width"? Can you show an example image of what you want to do?

Comment: @Sweeper Added image to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't familiar with `InsettableShape`, but with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65202819/20386264) I learned how it could be used.

The difficult part of this problem is working out the position for the triangle so that the edges of an inner triangle are equally spaced from the edges of an outer triangle. This requires a bit of trigonometry!

So here are two possible solutions, both using a `ZStack` to super-impose the shapes.

1. The first solution uses the basic `Shape` that you provided. A y-offset is then applied to adjust the position of the nested shapes. For this solution, the `ZStack` uses `alignment: .top`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let w: CGFloat = 250
    let h: CGFloat = 220

    private func yOffset(scalingFactor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let dW = w - (w * scalingFactor)
        let dH = h - (h * scalingFactor)
        let angle = atan2(2 * h, w)
        let sideSpace = (dW / 2) * sin(angle)
        return (dH * sideSpace) / (dH + sideSpace)
    }

    private func customShape(color: Color, scalingFactor: CGFloat = 1.0) -> some View {
        CustomShape()
            .fill(color)
            .overlay(
                CustomShape()
                    .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 5)
            )
            .frame(width: w * scalingFactor, height: h * scalingFactor)
            .offset(y: scalingFactor == 1.0 ? 0 : yOffset(scalingFactor: scalingFactor))
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            customShape(color: .purple)
            customShape(color: .pink, scalingFactor: 0.8)
            customShape(color: .orange, scalingFactor: 0.6)
            customShape(color: .yellow, scalingFactor: 0.4)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

2. In the second solution, the `Shape` has been converted to an `InsettableShape`. The function `yTop` is derived from the function `yOffset` from above. The `ZStack` uses default alignment this time.

```swift
struct CustomShape: InsettableShape {
    var insetAmount: CGFloat = 0

    private func innerHeight(w: CGFloat, h: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let ratio = h / w
        return ratio * (w - insetAmount - insetAmount)
    }

    private func yTop(w: CGFloat, h: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let dH = h - innerHeight(w: w, h: h)
        let angle = atan2(2 * h, w)
        let sideSpace = insetAmount * sin(angle)
        return (dH * sideSpace) / (dH + sideSpace)
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let yTop = insetAmount == 0 ? 0 : yTop(w: rect.width, h: rect.height)
        var x: CGFloat = insetAmount
        var y: CGFloat = yTop
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        x = rect.width - insetAmount
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        x = rect.width / 2
        y += innerHeight(w: rect.width, h: rect.height)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }

    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> some InsettableShape {
        var shape = self
        shape.insetAmount += amount
        return shape
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    private func customShape(color: Color, insetAmount: CGFloat = 0) -> some View {
        CustomShape()
            .inset(by: insetAmount)
            .fill(color)
            .strokeBorder(.black, lineWidth: 5)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            customShape(color: .purple)
            customShape(color: .pink, insetAmount: 25)
            customShape(color: .orange, insetAmount: 50)
            customShape(color: .yellow, insetAmount: 75)
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 220)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

I would say, implementing the shape in this way is more complicated. However, the calling code (in other words, `ContentView`) is now simpler and I like the way the knowledge of the shape is all contained inside the shape itself.

Both solutions give the same result:

[image: Triangles]

Comment: Answer updated to show how it can be solved using an ```InsettableShape``` too, as suggested in the post.

Answer (score 1):

This question is more about trigonometry than about coding. To create a good inset for the triangle, we first calculate the center of its inscribed circle. By converting the inset to a scale, we can then simply scale the shape around the center.

```
func square<T: Numeric>(_ value: T) -> T { value * value }

struct CustomShape: InsettableShape {
    var insetAmount: CGFloat = 0
    
    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> Self {
        var shape = self
        shape.insetAmount += amount
        return shape
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        guard !rect.isEmpty else { return Path() }

        // create the triangle
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.closeSubpath()
        
        // calculate the center of the inscribed circle
        // see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles
        let length = sqrt(square(rect.width / 2) + square(rect.height))
        let s = (rect.width + length * 2) / 2
        let r = sqrt((s - rect.width) * square(s - length) / s)
        
        let inCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY + r)
        
        // convert insetAmount to scale
        let scale = (rect.height - insetAmount * 2) / rect.height
        
        // scale around inCenter
        let transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
            .translatedBy(x: inCenter.x, y: inCenter.y)
            .scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
            .translatedBy(x: -inCenter.x, y: -inCenter.y)
        return path.applying(transform)
    }
}

struct CustomShapeView: View {
    
    let colors: [Color] = [.purple, .red, .orange, .yellow]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(colors.enumerated().map { $0 }, id: \.0) { index, color in
                CustomShape()
                    .inset(by: 25 * CGFloat(index))
                    .fill(color)
                CustomShape()
                    .inset(by: 25 * CGFloat(index))
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 5)
            }
        }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    }
}
```